# One controller isn't using my CSS and HTML structure but the other controllers are

Tags: ruby-on-rails

All the forms (new and show) for my Article controller are ignoring the layout (article.html.erb), whilst ALL my other controllers (e.g List) are applying the layout (lists.html.erb).

I have implemented SASS alongside my CSS and currently I have all my CSS defined within /assets/stylesheets/style.css.scss.

I can make changes to both the CSS and HTML structure and they are applied immediately to my application.

I am using the development environment and running ruby 1.9.3p125 and rails 3.2.1.

Can anyone suggest why this is happening?

The HTML layout for Lists controller is...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Inspire</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="home_container">
      <div id="header">
        <div id="home_user-space">
          <% if current_user %>
              <%= image_tag avatar_url(current_user), :class =>'floatleft' %>
              <%= link_to current_user.name.capitalize,user_path(:id =>current_user.name), :class =>'user-name' %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="navigation">
        <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
        <ul>
          <li><%= link_to "Log out", signout_path %></li>
          <li><%=  link_to "Your home page", home_path(:id => current_user.name), :class => 'user-name' %></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <div id="home_content-container">
        <div id="home_left-side">
          <%= render 'layouts/home_left_side' %>
        </div>
        <div id="home_content">
          <%= yield %>
        </div>
        <div id="home_right-side">
          <%= render 'layouts/home_right_side' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the layout for my Article controller is...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Inspire</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div id="home_container">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="home_user-space">
      <% if current_user %>
          <%= image_tag avatar_url(current_user), :class =>'floatleft' %>
          <%= link_to current_user.name.capitalize,user_path(:id =>current_user.name), :class =>'user-name' %>
      <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="navigation">
    <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to "Log out", signout_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="home_content-container">
    <div id="home_left-side">
      <%= render 'layouts/home_left_side' %>
    </div>
    <div id="home_content">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <div id="home_right-side">
      <%= render 'layouts/home_right_side' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--todo what about the footer-->
  <div id="footer">
    <%= render :partial => 'layouts/footer' %>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your article controller make sure you have:

```
# app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  layout "article"
  #...
end
```

Just an observation, but other than some whitespace your two layouts are identical. Why? Copy/paste error? If not, this begs the question: How do you know the article layout isn't being used? You can consult your development server log to see which layout is being used.

Also, perhaps you have set asset pipeline to compile your assets in development? Or run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`? If you do or have, delete the compile directory `/public/stylesheets/compiled`, make a change, and refresh your application in the browser.

If your layouts are mostly the same, you may want to [take advantage of nested layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts). They allow you to simply define one layout `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`, and replace small sections of it as needed for controllers or actions.

Comment: Your suggestion of using _layout "article_ works, so that's great thanks for that. I wasn't too aware of nested layouts - they sound like what I'm trying to achieve - thanks for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically giving the solution yourself:
You say that for List controller the layout file is `lists.html.erb` (plural) but for Article controller it is `article.html.erb` (singular)

Naming is important :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: You're right that the default is to look for the plural name, but layouts can be named whatever you want.